# How to use Special Fields in Formula?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have one section that can't appear in th second page (Can only appear in the first page)

[image: Selection Expert]

**First Page =** All of Above.

**Second Page =**  Only "Page Header a" and "Details".

I'm trying to use this formula: (this one is inside "Page Header b")

```
if {Page Number} <> "1" then
   true //Supress
else
   false
```

But I'm unable to reach {Page Number}, I already tried to use {PageNumber}...

So, How can I get the page number inside the formula workshop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PageNumber` is a keyword and doesn't require brackets. Also, it's a numeric data type, so your formula should just be `PageNumber<>1`